# Using re.match() to fix string capitalization

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am not getting the desired output for a particular problem I am trying to attempt on a website. Here is the problem:

> Let's consider that a word has been typed with the Caps lock key
>   accidentally switched on, if:
>
> either it only contains uppercase letters; or all letters except for
>   the first one are uppercase. In this case we should automatically
>   change the case of all letters. For example, the case of the letters
>   that form words "hELLO", "HTTP", "z" should be changed.
>
> Write a program that applies the rule mentioned above. If the rule
>   cannot be applied, the program should leave the word unchanged.

I have tried using the following code but I can't understand why it's not working as it should in my opinion.

```
import re
word = input()
exp = r'[a-z]+[A-Z]+'
exp2 = r'[A-Z]+'
if bool(re.match(word, exp)) or bool(re.match(word, exp2)):
    print(word[0].upper() + word[1:].lower())
else:
    print(word)
```

```
Input:CAPS
Desired output: Caps
Current output: CAPS

Input:cAPS
Desired output: Caps
Current output: cAPS

Input:cAPSlOCK
Desired output:cAPSlOCK
Current output: cAPSlOCK
```

Comment: Your question was down-voted because you are not explaining what you want your code to do exactly, nor showing effort to explain your current code. Please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I slightly modified  the regular expression in my answer based on the problem definition that you added, such that words starting with more than one lowercase letter are not modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first regular expression: `r'[a-z]+[A-Z]+'` matches a string starting with one or more lowercase letters followed by one or more uppercase letters.

The second regular expression `r'[A-Z]+'` matches a string starting with one or more uppercase letters.

You can combine them into: `r'[a-z]?[A-Z]+'` which matches a string starting with 0 or 1 lowercase letter followed by one or more uppercase letters.

Second, the order of parameters when calling `re.match()` is wrong. The first parameter should be the regular expression, second should be the string: `re.match(exp,word)`

Working implementation:

```
import re

word = input()
exp = r'[a-z]?[A-Z]+'
if bool(re.match(exp,word)):
    print(word[0].upper() + word[1:].lower())
else:
    print(word)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55438600